# How to call a Python script through wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm developing a plugin for wordpress where the user will be able to upload a file and have it analyzed. I have a Python script ready for the analysis, but I'm not sure on how to run it on PHP while passing arguments (the file's path). It would be optimal to have a solution that is also able to read a "print" from the Python script as output.

So far, I have something that looks like:

```
$handle = popen( __DIR__ . '/' . $data['file'], 'r' );
$read = '';

while ( ! feof( $handle ) )
{
    $read .= fread( $handle, 2096 );
}

pclose( $handle );

return $read;
```

But "popen" does not allow me to pass arguments. Any clues on the best way to do this?

Comment: This has nothing to do with Python, the question would be exactly the same with a binary program, a perl script or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

You can call Python script using PHP exec or shell_exec() functions, for example, you have a python file hello.py then you can call the file using below code

```
    exec("python hello.py",$output);
    print_r($output); //display the output
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
/* Plugin Name: Python embedded */

add_shortcode( 'python', 'embed_python' );

function embed_python( $attributes )
{
    $data = shortcode_atts(
        [
            'file' => 'hello.py'
        ],
        $attributes
    );

    $handle = popen( __DIR__ . '/' . $data['file'], 'r' );
    $read = '';

    while ( ! feof( $handle ) )
    {
        $read .= fread( $handle, 2096 );
    }

    pclose( $handle );

    return $read;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can read & write Python file by using the function [popen()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.popen.php). This function also works for other languages.

```
$handle = popen( __DIR__ . '/' . $file_name, 'r' );
$read = '';
while ( ! feof( $handle ) )
 {
   $read .= fread( $handle, 2096 );
 }
pclose( $handle );
```

[Reference](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/120259/running-a-python-script-within-wordpress)